# Set the input of a directive conditionally is not working

Tags: angular

I am using Anngular2 and I have the following directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[ngBlink]' })

export class BlinkDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('ngBlink') ngenableblink: string = "";
    private directiveTimeout;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {

    }

    private ApplyBlinking() {
        if (this.ngenableblink == "true") {
            if (this.el.nativeElement.className.indexOf("blinkIn") >= 0) {
                this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, "blinkIn", false); // remove class (blinkIn)
                this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, "blinkOut", true); // add class (blinkOut)
            } else if (this.el.nativeElement.className.indexOf("blinkOut") >= 0) {
                this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, "blinkOut", false); // remove class (blinkOut)
                this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, "blinkIn", true); // add class (blinkIn)
            }
            else {
                this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, "blinkOut", true); //Initially add (blinkOut) class
            }
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(this.directiveTimeout);
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.directiveTimeout = setInterval(() => this.ApplyBlinking(), 500);
    } }
```

and I want to set its value conditionally like following:

```
<label class="input-title"  [attr.ngBlink]="blinkTitle() ? true : false">Enter Key</label>
```

The label is rendered like this:

```
<label _ngcontent-qjd-8="" class="input-title" ngblink="true">Enter Key</label>
```

The problem is that the directive is not working (does not change the class element). But when I add the directive directly without using [attr.ngBlink] then it works fine:

```
<label _ngcontent-fif-8="" class="input-title blinkIn" ngblink="true">Enter Key</label>
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: Why are you using `[attr.ngBlink]` instead of `[ngBlink]` ?

Comment: @Aravind no I do not have any errors

Comment: @YounesM I am using it to conditionally set the value of ngBlink

Comment: You can do it by using `[ngBlink]`

Comment: Also is there a reason you do your test in the template ? Instead of having `blinkTitle()` returning a boolean ?

Comment: @YounesM thank you. It is working now :))

Comment: `[attr.ngBlink]="blinkTitle() ? true : false"` assigns the strings `'true'` or `'false'` because attributes only support string values. `[ngBlink]="blinkTitle() ? true : false"` is property binding and allows any value and will assign `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `[attr.someAttribute]` syntax is only for element attributes, not components/directives `@Input()`. You should use `[ngBlink]` directly.